# Counting documents that fit under certain query in a collection via Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've got a mongo database in my meteor app that has got a collection with documents formatted like:
key: value.

And I need to get count of documents whose value = x, y and z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CollectionName.find({keyName: {$in: [x, y, z]}}).count()
```

That query should work. I'm no expert but I'd imagine doing that count query on the server is a lot less taxing than sending 200k documents to the client!